# How to create a popup widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am building a photo editor in Flutter. At the bottom of my app, there is a toolbar. When the user clicks on the font size tool iconButton, I want a slider to appear. When the user is done adjusting the font size, it should disappear. I feel like this should be really simple, but can not find a concrete solution. Flutter only offers Popup menus, and I do not want to use a menu. I want to use a slider.

```
class Tools extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tools({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        //Change Font
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(BoxIcons.bx_font),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        //Change Font Size
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(BoxIcons.bx_font_size),
          onPressed: () {
            print("Tapped");
          },
        ),
        //Justify
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.format_align_left),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        //Change Color
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(BoxIcons.bx_font_color),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        //Add Stroke
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(LineAwesome.heading_solid),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        //Add Shadow
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Bootstrap.shadows),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

I need a custom popup widget for each of these tool options. I really am not sure how to go about doing this

Comment: you can use the alert dialog class in flutter
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html

Answer (score 0):

One way is to build your own management of the popup function using a stack where you only show the popup widget if a boolean expression is true. So something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class PopUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  PopUpScreen({super.key});
  var showPopUp = false;
  @override
  State<PopUpScreen> createState() => _PopUpScreenState();
}

class _PopUpScreenState extends State<PopUpScreen> {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        
        Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.format_size),
              onPressed: () {
                print("Tapped");
                setState(() {
                  widget.showPopUp = true;
                });
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.format_size),
              onPressed: () {
                print("Tapped");
                setState(() {
                  widget.showPopUp = true;
                });
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.format_size),
              onPressed: () {
                print("Tapped");
                setState(() {
                  widget.showPopUp = true;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if(widget.showPopUp)
        //Your popup widget
        Container(width: 200, height: 200, decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green), child: const Text("popup"),),

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

One problem with this implementation is the access/ownership of showPopUp i would suggest, if you are not already doing so, to use to use bloc pattern with streambuilder so this setState can be removed and the showPopUp can be moved to the bloc state